# AWS: S3 Bucket AWS You can't grant public access because Block public access settings are turned on for this account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I want to make S3 bucket public to everyone but I get access denied when I do That and it Says

```
You can't grant public access because Block public access settings 
are turned on for this account. To determine which settings are 
turned on, check your Block public access settings.
```

[image]

When I go to public access settings everything is turned off.

[image]

I did set IAM User and User has AmazonS3FullAccess policy

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
 }
```

I did set policy on the bucket

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1557294263403",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1557294241958",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::726051891502:user/borroup-admin"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::borroup",
            "arn:aws:s3:::borroup/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
 }
```

I did set CORS configuration editor on the bucket

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
<MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
<AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: have you succeed ?

Comment: @acubens Yes I did the Answer with screenshot below it got to work

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems like it has to be unchecked from both places Permissions and Block public access (account settings).

[image]

Comment: I think that the one on the left is for default values, while the tab in the bucket is for that specific bucket.

Comment: Is it just me or is this the worst part of AWS? Why can you not have block public access and then create a bucket policy to finer grain internal account permissions?

Comment: What does it mean public? is an account I have in aws is public? becuase using this feature blocks it. This doesn't make sense to block all accounts from accessing the bucket.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have sorted this out already, if not go to Edit public access settings
[image: Edit public access settings]

then type confirm in the next screen to go ahead with the change

[image: confirm]

Answer (score 1):

I had this same challenge when working on a Rails project where I was using AWS S3 bucket for storing images.

**Here's how I solved it**:

1. Click and open the bucket where the assets/images/files you want reside.

[image]

2. Click on the Permissions tab at the top menu of the bucket page

[image]

3. Click on Edit in the **Block public access (bucket settings)** section. And then untick **Block all public access**. Then save your changes.

[image]

**Note**: You can select the kind of public access that you want from the options given.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

In addition to walterc's answer, if anyone is still having problems I had to click into the specific file I wanted access to and click "Make Public" for that file as well since just Making the bucket public won't work for specific file link access.