# Serverless with S3 bucket to serve assets

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, serverless, bref

I use **Bref** (https://bref.sh/). I try to configure the *serverless.yml* file with **AWS S3** in order to store assets like img, css, js. When i deploy with "serverless deploy" command i have this error:

> An error occurred: AssetsBucketPolicy - API: s3:PutBucketPolicy Access
>   Denied.

In my AWS account, I have "AdministratorAccess" permissions (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KngM5bfpttA&list=PL0_-jlAhLRgEcU0P0Ivi4OO844pgrzJOU&index=2&t=0s)

strategy **AdministratorAccess**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

My serverless.yml file is:

```
service: bref-demo-symfony

provider:
    name: aws
    region: us-east-1
    runtime: provided
    environment:
        # Symfony environment variables
        APP_ENV: prod

plugins:
    - ./vendor/bref/bref

functions:
    website:
        handler: public/index.php
        timeout: 28 # in seconds (API Gateway has a timeout of 29 seconds)
        layers:
            - ${bref:layer.php-73-fpm}
        events:
            -   http: 'ANY /'
            -   http: 'ANY /{proxy+}'
    console:
        handler: bin/console
        timeout: 120 # in seconds
        layers:
            - ${bref:layer.php-73} # PHP
            - ${bref:layer.console} # The "console" layer

resources:
    Resources:
        # The S3 bucket that stores the assets
        Assets:
            Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
            Properties:
                BucketName: my-unique-serverless-assets-bucket
        # The policy that makes the bucket publicly readable
        AssetsBucketPolicy:
            Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
            Properties:
                Bucket: !Ref Assets # References the bucket we defined above
                PolicyDocument:
                    Statement:
                        -   Effect: Allow
                            Principal: '*' # everyone
                            Action: 's3:GetObject' # to read
                            Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::my-unique-serverless-assets-bucket/*' # things in the bucket
```

On AWS S3, i try to add a strategy on the bucket with

```
 {
  "Id": "Policy1573043469280",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1573043465451",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bref-demo-symfony-dev-serverless-assets/assets",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a message like "access denied", "You can't grant public access because Block public access settings 
are turned on for this account. To determine which settings are 
turned on, check your Block public access settings." Why ?

I don't understand how to configure it ? This permission (AdministratorAccess) is not enough?

Thank you!

Comment: I have the same error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56094367/s3-bucket-aws-you-cant-grant-public-access-because-block-public-access-settings

Comment: Here the solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56094474/611720

The left toggle menu hide me the option "Block public access (account settings)" on the S3 Management Console page

Answer (score -1):

From the docs, you can see this:

> To resolve the "Access Denied" error, check the following:
>
> Your IAM identity has permission to both `s3:GetBucketPolicy` and
>   `s3:PutBucketPolicy`.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-access-denied-bucket-policy/

Please check that the role you configured for your Lambda function has this permissions.

You can see this in the 'Execution role' section:
[image]
Here you can see my Lambda function has the role "claudia-express-executor".

You can also click on it, and check in details what that role permissions are.

Comment: i have AdministratorAccess permission
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}


i add AmazonS3FullAccess too
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Sorry, you keep saying *you* have AdministratorAccess, does the Lambda has them? Check my update

Answer (score -1):

1. Check the bucket policy
2. If there is a bucket policy involved add the user you created for the serverless
3. Check the image below for the sample bucket policy
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-bucket-policy.html[image]

Comment: I have a message like "access denied", "Granting public access in this policy will be blocked because public access blocking settings are enabled for this account and bucket. To identify the enabled settings, check your public access blocking settings."

Comment: Go in to your Bucket > Permissions > Public access settings > Edit > Untick Block new public ACLs and uploading public objects and Remove public access granted through public ACLs (warning)

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `iamRoleStatements` for example if you need get and put object add this code on the `iamRoleStatements` for example:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  region: us-west-2
  profile: ${self:custom.profiles.${self:custom.myStage}}
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "s3:PutObject"
        - "s3:GetObject"
      Resource:
        - "*"
```

This is another example:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: 'Allow'
      Action:
        - 's3:ListBucket'
      Resource:
        Fn::Join:
          - ''
          - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
            - Ref: ServerlessDeploymentBucket
    - Effect: 'Allow'
      Action:
        - 's3:PutObject'
      Resource:
        Fn::Join:
          - ''
          - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
            - Ref: ServerlessDeploymentBucket
            - '/*'
```

If you need more information read the serverless documentation:
[Serverless IAM Roles](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam/)

Comment: sorry, i dont succeed to do it. Thank for you help !

Comment: Try to add public access to your bucket